# Can System Center Essentials 2010 monitor both domain and non-domain Windows Servers?

Tags: windows-server-2008, monitoring, system-center-essentials

I need to be able to monitor two sets of Windows Server 2008 machines with System Center Essentials 2010.

1. One physical and 3 virtual (Hyper-V) servers in a domain configuration.
2. On the same LAN, but not in a domain configuration two physical and 3 virtual (Hyper-V) machines in a workgroup.

The non domain machines are public facing client web and database servers.

If I set-up a new VM inside the domain with System Center Essentials 2010 can I monitor the non domain servers?

If this isn't possible is there a Windows solution similar to System Center Essentials that can monitor domain and non domain machines in the same set up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is true for SCE 2007, excerpt from the System Centre forums FAQ

> Question 6: Can I monitor a machine that is in a workgroup?
>
> Answer:  Essentials requires that all managed computers are a member of a domain.

[Link to full FAQ](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/systemcenter/thread/c44515cb-fb8b-4472-a3d4-a17fa6729a03)

I assume this is the same for SCE 2010

Answer (score 1):

You can just join those computers to the domain and keep old users using / logging old profiles, except if you need to have them in a seperate workgroup.

Comment: You really missed the point. They're not in the domain because they're public-facing web and DB servers.